# Unable to read website intermittently with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried to read a website using Python `requests`.

However, it sometimes succeeds but sometimes fails.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://hn.house.ifeng.com/homedetail/25762.shtml'
res = requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout = 10, verify=False)
```

What are the reasons and how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you share more about the success and failure conditions?

Comment: Try increasing the timeout value .